# Using regex OR to replace strings that have either (:) or (=)

Tags: json, regex

I have instances of JSON in the following format - `"firstName":"sample"` and `"firstName"="sample"`. I am trying to modify my regex for the colon that replaced the `"sample"` with asterisks to include cases where instead of a colon there is an equal sign.

```
\"firstName\"\s*:\s*\"(.*?)\"
```

I tried adding an OR -

```
\"firstName\"\s*(:|=)\s*\"(.*?)\"
```

However, this gives me the following output --> `"firstName" * "******************"` for cases with the colon as well as an equals sign. The expected output should not replace the colon or equals, only what is inside the string. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\"firstName\"\s*[:|=]\s*\"(.*?)\"
```